# Chrome flexbox with percentage based height behavior is incorrect

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox

I have a flexbox with 2 lists.  The flexbox is inside an absolute positioned parent with a defined height.  The top list has items that are more important to me, so I want them to grow first and get a scroll bar last.  The bottom list should grow last and get a scroll bar first.

So in other words the behavior I want is:

1. If too many items in both lists, the bottom list should be at the minimum height w/ a scrollbar and the top list should fill the remaining space with a scrollbar.
2. If too many items in the bottom list, it should fill all the space not used by the top list, then get a scroll bar.
3. If too many items in the top list, behavior is same as #1 and bottom list doesn't have to have a scrollbar if it doesn't need one.

You will find the correct behavior here. Specifically from Microsoft Edge but generally from "Not Chrome" [image: Correct behavior]

Chrome fails at recreating situation #1. It will allow the list to grow greater than the parent no matter what I do:

[image: Bad Browser]

The jsFiddle used to create the screenshots is here. https://jsfiddle.net/drLs8tgo/  I appreciate any advice to get my desired behavior.

```
<div class="layout">
  <div class="flexContainer">
    <div class="grow">
      <div class="growHeader">
        Important Items
      </div>
      <div class="growBody">
        <ul id="growList">
          <li>Grow</li>
          <li>Grow</li>
          <li>Grow</li>
          <li>Grow</li>
          <li>Grow</li>
          <li>Grow</li>
          <li>Grow</li>
          <li>Grow</li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shrink">
      <div class="shrinkHeader">
        Some Items
      </div>
      <div class="shrinkBody">
        <ul id="shrinkList">
          <li>Shrink</li>
          <li>Shrink</li>
          <li>Shrink</li>
          <li>Shrink</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="toolbar">
  <button id="growAdd">Add Grow Item</button>
  <button id="growRemove">Remove Grow Item</button>
  <button id="shrinkAdd">Add Shrink Item</button>
  <button id="shrinkRemove">Remove Shrink Item</button>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
div.layout {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
}

div.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div.grow {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  height: auto;
  max-height: calc(100% - 120px);
}

div.shrink {
  height: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 120px;
}

div.growHeader,
div.shrinkHeader {
  background: grey;
  height: 40px;
}

div.growBody,
div.shrinkBody {
 height: calc(100% - 40px);
 max-height: calc(100% - 40px);
 overflow: auto;

  > ul {
   max-height: 100%;
  }
}

div.toolbar {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  top: 500px;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this work how you want? https://jsfiddle.net/drLs8tgo/1/

Comment: No because the "Important Items" header is inside the scroll area.

Comment: Better with this?: https://jsfiddle.net/drLs8tgo/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the `.grow` and `.shrink` items also flex containers, you can achieve that.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/drLs8tgo/4/)

```js
var growAdd = document.getElementById('growAdd');
var growRemove = document.getElementById('growRemove');
var shrinkAdd = document.getElementById('shrinkAdd');
var shrinkRemove = document.getElementById('shrinkRemove');
growAdd.addEventListener("click", addGrowElement, false);
growRemove.addEventListener("click", removeGrowElement, false);
shrinkAdd.addEventListener("click", addShrinkElement, false);
shrinkRemove.addEventListener("click", removeShrinkElement, false);

function addGrowElement() {
  var olList = document.getElementById('growList');
  var newListItem = document.createElement('li');
  newListItem.innerText = 'Grow';
  olList.appendChild(newListItem);
}

function removeGrowElement() {
  var olList = document.getElementById('growList');
  olList.removeChild(olList.children[0]);
}

function addShrinkElement() {
  var olList = document.getElementById('shrinkList');
  var newListItem = document.createElement('li');
  newListItem.innerText = 'Shrink';
  olList.appendChild(newListItem);
}

function removeShrinkElement() {
  var olList = document.getElementById('shrinkList');
  olList.removeChild(olList.children[0]);
}
```

```css
div.layout {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
}

div.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div.grow {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  max-height: calc(100% - 120px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div.shrink {
  flex: 1 0 0px;
  min-height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div.growHeader,
div.shrinkHeader {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: grey;
  height: 40px;
}

div.growBody,
div.shrinkBody {
 flex-grow: 1;
 overflow: auto; 
}

div.toolbar {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  top: 500px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="flexContainer">
    <div class="grow">
      <div class="growHeader">
        Important Items
      </div>
      <div class="growBody">
        <ul id="growList">
          <li>Grow</li>
          <li>Grow</li>
          <li>Grow</li>
          <li>Grow</li>
          <li>Grow</li>
          <li>Grow</li>
          <li>Grow</li>
          <li>Grow</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shrink">
      <div class="shrinkHeader">
        Some Items
      </div>
      <div class="shrinkBody">
        <ul id="shrinkList">
          <li>Shrink</li>
          <li>Shrink</li>
          <li>Shrink</li>
          <li>Shrink</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="toolbar">
  <button id="growAdd">Add Grow Item</button>
  <button id="growRemove">Remove Grow Item</button>
  <button id="shrinkAdd">Add Shrink Item</button>
  <button id="shrinkRemove">Remove Shrink Item</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.